# Show counter result in dashboard

Tags: laravel

I would like to create a dasboard with Laravel 8. I want to count all tickets in the database and display the number in the dashboard. Unfortunately it does not work do you have an idea?

*Controller Code*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Models\Ticket;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
      //
        $ticketsCount = Ticket::count();     
        return view('dashboard.index', compact('ticketsCount'));
    }
}
```

*View Code*

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-info">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3>{{ $ticketsCount->count() }}</h3>

                <p>Open Tickets</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
              </div>
              <a href="{{ url('tickets') }}" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: If you're calling `::count()`, you can't then call `->count()`. You're basically doing `(integer)->count()`, which is not valid... You already have the number, just do `{{ $ticketsCount }}`...

Comment: "_Unfortunately it does not work_" is not a very precise description of your problem. Do you get a white page? Wrong count? No count?

Comment: @brombeer Good call :) I would suspect they're getting the error *"Call to a member function count() on int"*, whether error reporting is turned on is a different question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, your router returns view file, and not getting into controller.

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard.index');
});
```

change your router to (Laravel version before 8)

`Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');`

After Laravel version 8

`use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;`

`Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index']);`

**[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#the-default-route-files)**

Comment: Thank you very much... that was the solution, it work... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `->count()` from your view, you already counted it in controller
`$ticketsCount = Ticket::count();`

**The view code:**

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-info">
              <div class="inner">
                <h3>{{ $ticketsCount }}</h3>

                <p>Open Tickets</p>
              </div>
              <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-bag"></i>
              </div>
              <a href="{{ url('tickets') }}" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Made the change in the view -> {{ $ticketsCount }}. 
Now I get the following error message: 
Undefined variable: ticketsCount

Comment: Does the View corresponds the `dashboard.index` file? Does it located in the `/resources/views/dashboard/index.blade.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get the number of users displayed on the view. Unfortunately I always get an error message...

**Error:**

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: counter (View: /laravel/resources/views/dashboard/index.blade.php)
```

**Route (web):**

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard.index');
});
```

**Model (Dashboard)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dashboard extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

}
```

**Controller (DashboardController)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DashboardController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
      $counter = DB::table('users')->count();
      return view('dashboard.index', compact('counter'));
    }
}
```

**View (dashboard/index.blade.php):**

```
Users: {{ $counter }}
```

Comment: Hello @CodeNinja71, check my new answer